# Sharepoint 2010 enterprise search sql syntax

Tags: search, sql

sorry for the bad English.
So i'm using SharePoint 2010 server Enterprise Search and I'm building a custom search webpart and result page.
Using the SQL syntax:
 **Select (whatever i need) from scope() where "myScope" = 'MyDeviceScope' AND Camera != ''**
So *Camera* is a single line text managed property i want to find where this property has any text in it.
The wildcard operator doesn't help me much cause I don't know what will be entered in this single line of text the client enters it from a custom layout i've made.

Thank You.

Comment: SQL Syntax is deprecated in SharePoint 2010 and removed in 2013. Have you tried using Keyword Query Syntax? It does not appear that you query is overly complicated. KQL supports AND and NOT operators.

Comment: If run a bit of testing and search and found that if I use Camera <> '""' it works but if i add CONTAINS(someField, 
'"FieldValue"') it trows exception